# question regarding jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div id="foo">yyy<span>xxx</span></div>
```

I have the the above structure for my html. I want to insert some content at yyy position. Can you let me know what will be the selector for it?
I would pass that selector to somefunction and that function will do `$(selector).html('content')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var s = $('#foo span');
$('#foo').text("hello").append(s);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uTNTF/

Or, if updating the HTML is an option, then simply wrapping `yyy` in a `<span>` will make your life a lot simpler:

```
$('#foo span:first-child').text("hello");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uTNTF/1/

Comment: This is probably the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) function (insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements):

```
$('#foo').prepend('some content');
```

Comment: alternatively `$('#foo span').before(...)`. (esp if you had multiple elements and wanted something inserted between them)

Comment: This will not remove 'yyy' and insert my content.

Answer (score 1):

`yyy` should rellay be in a block element to allow you to easily discover it, otherwise I see no option other than the hacky:

```
$('#foo').html($('#foo').html().replace('yyy','')).find('span').before('new content');
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/MTu6c/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single magic selector that will select some plain text inside a container but not all of of the content.

If you want to replace 'yyy' with 'some content', you could do something like the following:

```
$('#foo').html('some content' + $('#foo span').html())
```

Answer (score 0):

The "yyy" portion of the markup you posted is represented in the DOM as a text node. jQuery doesn't have any methods or selectors for isolating text nodes, but the DOM does.

See here (your question might be considered a duplicate of this one):
[How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)